# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getUid()' on a null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-studio-3.0

In my android app, I have uploaded user image using signup activity. After being registered, MainActivity will be loaded and user image need to be displayed in an imageview. But no image is getting displayed and getting the below

error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getUid()' on a null object reference
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;


    String post_key = null;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
    private TextView txt,url;
    private ImageView profilePic;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.homeico,
          
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        profilePic = findViewById(R.id.userimg);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());
        StorageReference storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference();

        storageReference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Images").child("Profile Pic").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
               
               Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(uri).into(profilePic);

            }
        });
       


        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
       
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "Home");
       
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            return null;

        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error? Are you also sure the user is authenticated when you call `.getUid()`?

Comment: Not sure, pretty beginner.

Answer (score 0):

In order to `getUid()` to work, you will need to first get the current user signed in to get the ID

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;


    String post_key = null;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
    private TextView txt,url;
    private ImageView profilePic;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.homeico,

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        profilePic = findViewById(R.id.userimg);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().get;

        FirebaseUser currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null && currentUser.getUid() != null) {
            {
                DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(currentUser.getUid());
                StorageReference storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference();

                storageReference.child(currentUser.getUid()).child("Images").child("Profile Pic").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                        Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(uri).into(profilePic);

                    }
                });



                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

                viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                setupViewPager(viewPager);

                tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                setupTabIcons();
            }
        }}

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);

    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "Home");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            return null;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where to fit this code in mainactivity? please suggest.

Comment: yes inside your MainActivity . whereever you have written `firebaseAuth.getUid()` just replace with above code with Null check

Comment: i am beginner in this field. Tried to put but don't know where i m doing wrong.Please edit my code with you suggestion and share.

Comment: Also on hovering on currentUser.getUid() method, it is showing - Condition 'currentUser.getUid() != null' is always true when reached.

Comment: Anyone out there to help, please respond.